# Getting APK file from my project

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I just press right on my appproject and choose Android Tools --> Export Unsigned Application Package...

But if i want to install the apk on my phone the install process dont finish

What do i have made wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In eclipse you you go to run->build or if you have build automatically turned on you can go into the projects file structure and just copy the .apk file out of the bin folder. You can put this on the devices SD card and install it from there. No need to do the export unsigned apk thing.

Comment: You shouldn't use this .apk for any purpose other than testing.

Answer (score 3):

The .apk must be signed.

Eclipse auto-generates an .apk signed with a debugging key at bin/YourApp.apk. It's ok to use this file for testing purposes, but you shouldn't give this .apk to customers or end-users because you won't be able to update this app in the future.

If you intend to publish this .apk to your customers you should use your own key to sign the .apk. Read: [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you enabled 'Unknown sources' within the applications section of your phone settings.

Answer (score 0):

> If you already running your project on emulator,you just close that emulator.And goes to

```
Project->clean
Project->BuildProject.
```

> And then run your project in emulator and then check it out

```
bin/res/your.apk file
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Export Signed" instead of "Export Unassigned".

Google does not allow Android System to install "Export Unassigned" apk, see here -> http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html.

To "Export signed", read here -> http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/23/build-android-application-package-file-apk-using-eclipse-ide-and-android-development-tools-adt-plugin